# Read more than one MAX31865

Tags: c#, .net, iot, gpio, raspberry-pi4

We are implementing temperature reading using **PT100 (3 wires)** and Raspberry 4 with .NET 6.

We are able to read the temperature using as reference this [article](https://github.com/dotnet/iot/tree/main/src/devices/Max31865).

```cs
SpiConnectionSettings settings = new(0, 0)
{
    ClockFrequency = Max31865.SpiClockFrequency,
    Mode = Max31865.SpiMode1,
    DataFlow = Max31865.SpiDataFlow
};

using (SpiDevice device = SpiDevice.Create(settings))
{
    using (Max31865 sensor = new(device, PlatinumResistanceThermometerType.Pt100, ResistanceTemperatureDetectorWires.ThreeWire, ElectricResistance.FromOhms(430)))
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sensor.Faults.ToString());

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually to work the script need the `CS` pin of `Max31865` connected to pin 12 of raspberry GPIO. We would like to connect more than one `Max31865` in order to record some temperatures from different `Pt100`.

How we can specify the right/specific GPIO port in the C# script for every `Max31865` `CS` output pin? Actually seems there are no properties to change that pin but this feature will permit us to read more than one sensor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing is to do the CS handling manually, as automatic CS handling with multiple devices on the same bus is not fully implemented for the Raspberry Pi.

```cs
var controller = new GpioController();
controller.OpenPin(CsPinOfSensor1);
controller.OpenPin(CsPinOfSensor2);
controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor1, PinValue.Low); // CS is low-active!
controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor2, PinValue.High);
using Max31865 sensor1 = new(device, PlatinumResistanceThermometerType.Pt100, ResistanceTemperatureDetectorWires.ThreeWire, ElectricResistance.FromOhms(430));
controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor1, PinValue.High); // CS is low-active!
controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor2, PinValue.Low);
using Max31865 sensor2 = new(device, PlatinumResistanceThermometerType.Pt100, ResistanceTemperatureDetectorWires.ThreeWire, ElectricResistance.FromOhms(430));
    {

        while (true)
        {
            controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor1, PinValue.Low); // CS is low-active!
            controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor2, PinValue.High);
            Console.WriteLine(sensor1.Temperature.ToString());

            controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor1, PinValue.High);
            controller.Write(CsPinOfSensor2, PinValue.Low);
            Console.WriteLine(sensor2.Temperature.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

There are multiple pins reserved as CS pins for each SPI bus, but I honestly do not even know how they would need to be selected at the OS level.

Alternatively, you can of course also connect the second sensor to a second SPI bus. The Raspberry Pi4 has a total of 6 SPI channels.